# yum install error nothing to do (MYSQL, CentOS 7)

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, vps

I'm trying to install MYSQL instead of MariaDB on my CentOS 7. I used this command:

`wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm`

`yum install http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm`

`rpm -Uvh http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm`

as root. but i got error and nothing happen:

`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm                 | 5.2 kB     00:00
Cannot open: http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do`

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

you have tried from banned countries. if you open the link in your browser you would see the message "In compliance with U.S. and applicable Export laws we are unable to process your request.  Please contact RPLS-Ops_ww@oracle.com if you believe you are receiving this notice in error."
you should download using another ip provided by vpn or proxy.

Answer (score 1):

The **wget** command will download the package to your current directory . Once it is downloaded you can simply install it using the **rpm** command with the package name and not the complete link as

```
rpm -Uvh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
```

In case this shows some unfulfilled dependencies , you can use

```
yum localinstall mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
```

to try and install the dependencies as well from the repositories.

Comment: thanks, but none of those command i write work. even wget so it seams i have no package on my vps. and can i ask u what version of MYSQL is it  ?

Comment: Not sure what specific version you are trying to download here but you can just go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and download the latest mysql community server(the one for redhat 7 should work on centos 7 too) and then install it using rpm or yum.

Comment: I could get package with wget but when i run this : `2016-06-23 15:19:31 (18.6 KB/s) - ‘mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm’ saved [5305/5305]

[root@VPS-**** ~]# rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
error: mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest):
` I get this error

Comment: This error usually occurs when the rpm is corrupted . Please check if the file was downloaded properly or you can download the complete package itself from link i gave and then try to install .